# Automation processes using List of commands

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, teechart

So, I am making a program designed to complete some automated process.  I have a form that allows the user to build custom automation processes.  The structure of this automation process is as follows:

```
    public class AutomationScript
    {
        public string FilePath;
        public List<AutomationEvent> Events;

        public AutomationScript()
        {
            Events = new List<AutomationEvent>();
        }
    }

    public class AutomationCommand
    {
        public AutomationCommandType Type;
        public int Parameter;

        public AutomationCommand(AutomationCommandType _type, int _parameter)
        {
            Type = _type;
            Parameter = _parameter;
        }
    }

    public struct AutomationEvent
    {
        public string Name;
        public bool LoopEnabled;
        public List<AutomationCommand> Commands;
    }

    public enum AutomationCommandType
    {
        WaitSecs,
        CollectSample,
        CollectBackGround,
        StopCollection,
        LoopStart,
        LoopEnd,
    }
```

Now, when the user initiates the process to run a thread is created and it iterates through the commands.  The basic setup is as follows:

```
        private void runAutomationScript()
        {
            while (automationON)
            {
                foreach (AutomationEvent aEvent in fullAutomationScript.Events)
                {
                    int loopStartIndex = 0;
                    int loopEndIndex = 0;
                    foreach (AutomationCommand command in aEvent.Commands)
                    {
                        while (!CommandCompleted) { } //Will stay in loop until the hardware module is finished receiving spectra
                        switch (command.Type)
                        {
                            case AutomationCommandType.CollectBackGround:
                                RequestedBackgroundScans = command.Parameter;
                                spectralCollection.getBackGroundSpectra(RequestedBackgroundScans);
                                CommandCompleted = false;
                                break;
                            case AutomationCommandType.CollectSample:
                                RequestedSampleScans = command.Parameter;
                                spectralCollection.getSampleSpectra(RequestedSampleScans);
                                CommandCompleted = false;
                                break;
                            case AutomationCommandType.WaitSecs:
                                Thread.Sleep(command.Parameter * 1000);
                                break;
                            case AutomationCommandType.StopCollection:
                                automationON = false;
                                break;
                            case AutomationCommandType.LoopStart:
                                loopStartIndex = aEvent.Commands.IndexOf(command);
                                break;
                            case AutomationCommandType.LoopEnd:
                                loopEndIndex = aEvent.Commands.IndexOf(command);
                                //Wehn the loop end is reached it will get the index of the start and end and grab a sublist and iterate over that continuously.
                                int firstCommandIndex = loopStartIndex + 1;
                                List<AutomationCommand> loopedCommands = aEvent.Commands.GetRange(firstCommandIndex, loopEndIndex - firstCommandIndex );
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            OnAutomationFinished(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

Now, at this point it works fine.  I am trying to allow the user to define a loop point for the process to loop through.  As you can see there is an `AutomationCommand` called `LoopStart` and `LoopEnd`.  I am trying to figure out how to loop through this second sub loop without copying code into another function.  I am toying with the idea of making some recursive definition of this command loop.  Any ideas will help.

Comment: The reason for the `CommandCompleted`is because the spectral collection is done by events. So, when the commands to get spectral data are initiated the loop must wait until these events are done firing.

Comment: This question got my attention because it has the TeeChart tag. I wonder how TeeChart fits in your application and if you have any doubts about its usage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Teechart is great.  I don't have any doubts about its usage but one.  I am performing this automated process to do to do quantification analysis on an absorption plot to test for gas impurities.  I am storing these results in a result stream (Queue).  ANyway, the application is an MDI spectral collection service.  Each mdi child contains a chart.  The user can view concentration results per molcule or group.  I am trying to keep everything simple by keeping all my chart series in one location and chart them wherever I need. Thing is when I apply a series to a chrt it gets taken away frm others

Comment: I want to be able to chart the sme series on multiple charts if I need to.  Thing is, a series can only be assigned to one chart.  Or at least that's what I believe.  SO instead, I have to create copies of every fastline in every child and do consistancy checks and updates on the main stream as well as streams in each child.

Comment: TeeChart Series will always make internal x,y (& z if applicable) arrays for Series to be associated with a Chart or plotted. There are some effective ways of connecting to data of another Series, loading data into a dataset and Series with Series.Clone() method or Copy function, and using CheckDataSource() to verify consistency between Series. I also added your request to the bugzilla to be considered for inclusion in future releases: http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=801

Comment: as an update to this issue, you might be interested in the solution suggestion here: http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=801#c1. Feel free to sign up at bugzilla to add your own issues/comments and receive automatic notifications.